# Alright this might sound stupid. Why do we expand by 10?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, self-learning, education

Specifically the math problem 90.5b+21*92/21+b=91.2. The math calculator on the internet kept giving me errors when I put it in like that. So I changed it to 90.5b+1932/21+b=91.2, and it gave me an answer with step by step so I could follow along. Honesty first time hearing distributive property in a math problem, but easy enough to understand once I saw what it did for the problem. What I don't quite understand is the second to last step of the problem. ***It says expand by 10. So my question is why? Where does this 10 come from? Without this 10 the answer is 2.4, but with it it becomes 24***. This math problem I got from a word problem involving students, but even just numbers it answers 24. Which brought up the questions in bold and italic. I'm not to bright so treat this like you're speaking to a 4th grader please? Incase anyone is wondering since I messed up even after seeing the steps (distributive property got me) the steps are

```
                         90.5b+(21*92)/21+b=91.2

                         90.5b+1932/21+b=91.2

                         90.5b+1932(/21+b*21+b)=91.2(21+b)

                 90.5b+1932=(91.2*21)+(91.2*b) (this is that distributive property part)

                         90.5b+1932=1915.2+91.2b

                        (90.5b-91.2b)+1932=1915.2+(91.2b-91.2b)

                         -0.7b+1932=1915.2

                         -0.7b+(1932-1932)=1915.2-1932

                         -0.7b=-16.8
```

(This is the part I don't get) -0.7x10=-16.8x10 (not sure why the * didn't work in final draft)

```
                         -7b=-168

                         -168/-7=b

                          b=24
```

I know a lot of people are smarter than me, and didn't need the step by step. But hey it's there so if it helps great. Thanks for your time on what is probably an easy answer.

Comment: A math calculator on the internet that's usually trustworthy: [90.5b+21*92/21+b=91.2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=90.5b%2B21*92%2F21%2Bb%3D91.2)

Comment: From $-0.7b = -16.8$, either you divide both sides by $-0.7$ to perform a division of decimal fractions: $b = \dfrac{-16.8}{-0.7}$. Or first multiply both sides by $10$ and perform a division of integers: $b = \dfrac{-168}{-7}$. The answers are the same.

Comment: What is the calculator you're using? If you've reproduced its output verbatim, then it's certainly not using standard mathematical notation, or interpreting its input in a standard way.  The expression 1932(/21+b*21+b) appearing in the third line, for instance,  is meaningless.

Comment: Sorry if I made a mess of it. The question I meant to ask was why are we multiplying by ten? What caused us to multiply those numbers by ten? As for the third line it was meant to show them cancelling each other out. Like I said I'm not the brightest so I was trying to the process of the steps.

Comment: here's a link to the calculator https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/(1932%2B90.5%20%60times%20%20b)%20%60div%20%20(21%2Bb)%3D91.2?r=bi&ref=bi

Comment: here's a link to [the same calculator if I paste your equation `90.5b+21*92/21+b=91.2`](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/90.5b%2B%20%60frac%7B%2021%20%60cdot%20%2092%20%20%7D%7B%2021%20%20%7D%20%20%2Bb%20%3D%20%2091.2)

Comment: Please use parenthesis in division or [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format. We multiply $10$ on both sides to remove decimals which may be tedious to divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you multiply by 10: **to make the numbers easier to calculate**.  It's as simple as that.

Dividing whole numbers is easier than dividing fractions; since both of the numbers involved has one decimal place, then multiplying by 10 will turn them into integers.  (If one of them had two decimal places, you'd need to multiply them by 10² = 100 to get integers; and so on.)

It's not strictly needed: you'd get the same end result without multiplying by 10.  But it's very easy to do, and makes the division easier.

(And why you *can* multiply by 10: because you're multiplying *both sides* by the same number, so the equality still holds.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I realized after reading your answer my mistake of not moving the decimal place after division which multiplying by 10 removed the need for. Sorry for wasting everyone's time

Comment: @RyanMalloy It's been said that there's no such thing as a stupid question.  While that's not _entirely_ true (!), this one's a perfectly valid question — and you don't know who else might benefit from seeing it discussed here.  (We all have to start somewhere!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I am looking at in that equation. Looking at the first equation in the post, I see $90.5b+21\times\frac{92}{21}+b=91.2$. This from your post "90.5b+21*92/21+b=91.2" And this yields something like -.008. I think you might have left out some parenthesis.

Comment: My fault it's supposed to 90.5 times b + (92 times 21) divided by 21 + b = 91.2. The star symbol is sometimes used as multiplication.

Comment: ($90.5×b+21×92)/21+b=91.2$ Hope that looks right honestly not used to writing equations on pc like this. If it doesn't look any better here's another way to show 90.5×b+21×92 are both divided by 21+b and equal 91.2

Comment: Sorry, but in the second reply, you are still contradicting yourself.  The second sentence says there should be parenthesis around 21 + b in the denominator.